# Tweepy not working no error message

Tags: python, tweepy

I installed the latest Tweepy in Python 3.4.1 then ran this code

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function

from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream

# Go to http://apps.twitter.com and create an app.
# The consumer key and secret will be generated for you after
consumer_key=""
consumer_secret=""

# After the step above, you will be redirected to your app's page.
# Create an access token under the the "Your access token" section
access_token=""
access_token_secret=""



class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
    """ A listener handles tweets are the received from the stream.
    This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
    """
    def on_data(self, data):
        print(data)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    stream = Stream(auth, l)
    stream.filter(track=['happy'])
```

When I run the code nothing happens in the console at all. I have checked that running import tweepy works and that I am running an administrator console and the codes are correct ... But nothing.

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: May be no "happy" tweets so far? :)

Comment: haha its been running since you posted that... nothing :P

Comment: try using some recent trends like `"#parisAttack"` to check if that works ?

Comment: Does not work :( [this](http://i.imgur.com/fDGWM2v.png) is what I get. Left it running for a few hours and nothing else happened

Comment: I'm getting the same result with python 3, though it does seem to work with python 2.